# How to add a timer to a function - IOS Swift

Tags: ios, function, swift, timer

Say I had a function, any function, that I wanted to run for only three seconds and then never run again. How would I do this? Would I use NSTimer? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("updateProgress:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func updateProgress(timer: NSTimer){
}
```